# How to get file name when file change is observed via watch_file

Tags: file, julia, file-watcher

I am currently facing an issue which I don't know how to fix. I got the following Julia code:

```
while true
    print(watch_file("test"))
end
```

So this should get me all the file changes in the directory named "test". At least on windows.

Now thats all well and good, and it kinda works, at least for creating a file or moving a file to that directory. This is an example of what I get:

```
("New Textfile.txt",Base.FileEvent(true,false,false))
```

But when I delete or rename that file, I don't get the filename of the file deleted or renamed.

```
("",Base.FileEvent(true,false,false))
```

Is there a different method/function I can get the filename with, even when the file is deleted or renamed? Or even better, a way that archives this and is cross-platform-compatible? Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:** If you could give me an alternative that supports recursive monitoring, that would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, Julia 0.4.5 and 0.4.3 watch_file returns file name always. It is a very platform-dependent feature (like in Node.js https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_caveats) and only manual polling can be truly platform-independent solution.